# Update joomla 3.4.5 to 3.7.5 and get error 500

Tags: joomla

I have tried to update from 3.4.5 to 3.7.5 but only get error 500 when I press the button. I have tried to import the update as a zip file, but then I got errormessage 403 access denied. When I tried to update whit the tar.bz2 file I got errormessage:

> COM_INSTALLER_MSG_INSTALL_WARNINSTALLUPLOADERROR

I using PHP version 5.4.45 and MySQL version 5.1.73.

How do I update my Joomlapage?

Answer (score 1):

These are possible causes:

1. Check your options on Admin Tools or any other security/firewall extensions you have.  Since this is a one time install, you might just try disabling the entire component/plugin for a minute to run upgrade.
2. Check your .htaccess file.  Again, you can just temporarily remove and try to run upgrade.
3. Your PHP version might contribute as well since Joomla 3.7 recommends PHP 5.6+: https://downloads.joomla.org/us/technical-requirements-us